# hibernate validation doesn't happen on persist in database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, persistence, hibernate-validator

I have the following session factory configuration:

```
     <session-factory>
        <property name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-persist">javax.validation.groups.Default</property>
        <property name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-update">javax.validation.groups.Default</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.showSql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
        <mapping class="com.terminal.domain.Terminal"/>
        ...
    </session-factory>
```

Terminal class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "terminal")
public class Terminal {
    @Column(name = "cost")
    @Min(100)
    private Long cost;
    // get and set
}
```

I have the following code in my service method:

```
Terminal terminal = new Terminal();
terminal.setCost(98L);
session.save(terminal);
```

When I invoke it new row adds in `terminal` table.
expected result: validation exception and new row doesn't add in `terminal` table.

Why does actual result differs from expected ?

**P.S.**

As I understood it should work out of the box
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-checkconstraints.html#validator-checkconstraints-orm-hibernateevent

**P.P.S.**

hibernate stuff dependencies:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

### RESOLUTION

The problem is disappeared after making following steps:

**1.** migrate libary versions:

`hibernate-core`:   3.3.2.GA -> 4.3.10.Final
`hibernate-annotations`: 3.3.1.GA -> 3.5.6-Final
`hibernate-commons-annotations`: 3.3.0.ga -> 3.2.0.Final
`hibernate-validator`: 4.2.0.Final -> 5.1.3.Final

removed dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**2.** replaced in configuration

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean
```

with

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
 </bean
```

**3.** and for session factory:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate-test.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>
```

with

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate-test.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**4.** session factory configuration:

```
<session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.showSql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
        ...//classes mapping
</session-factory>
```

---

Actually I didn't understand which concrete step resolved my problem but in complex it is really works

Comment: Just at least to understand if everything is working correctly.. 
If you do something like this..

   Terminal terminal = new Terminal();
   terminal.setCost(98L);
   ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
   Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
   Set<ConstraintViolation<Terminal>> constraintViolations = validator.validate( terminal );
   if (constraintViolations != null && constraintViolations.size() > 0)
   {
    // handle your exception here
   }
   else
   {
   session.save(terminal);
   }
are the annotation considere by the explicit validator?

Comment: Did you get the solution for this?

Comment: @Rohit Yes, topic updated

Comment: @witchedwiz topic updated

Comment: I think the change of the transaction manager did the trick

Answer (score 1):

The configuration properties you are referencing apply to JPA. If you are using the JPA API it should work. It looks like that you are using the native Hibernate ORM Session API. You need to use the `EntityManager` API.

Comment: Sorry,  for stupid question, but how to understand I use JPA Api or native hibernate session api?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using JPA, you need to add the following EntityManager listeners:

```
<event type="pre-update">
    <listener class="org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener"/>
</event>
<event type="pre-insert">
    <listener class="org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener"/>
</event>
<event type="pre-delete">
    <listener class="org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener"/>
</event>
```

And also add the following property:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode">
  ddl, callback
</property>
```

If you are using Hibernate specific configuration, with `hibernate.cfg.xml`, then the configs become:

```
 <event type="pre-update">
   <listener class="org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener"/>
</event>
<event type="pre-insert">
    <listener class="org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener"/>
</event>
<event type="pre-delete">
    <listener class="org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener"/>
</event>
```

Comment: when I added events into my hibernate.cfg.xml I see the following error "the content of element type 'session-factory' must match '(property*, mapping*,*class-cache|collection-cache)*, event*, listener)'."

Comment: maybe I use inconsistent hibernate versions?

Comment: Those are for persistence.xml.

Comment: Mmm,  sorry, I am not a hibernate guru. I have only hibernate. cfg.xml

Comment: looks lke you copied same config as for JPA. I see old error

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Hibernate validator.
Here the maven artifact

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
<version>5.1.3.Final</version>
```

Here the getting start documentation.

http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/

Comment: Do you think that I use wrong version of hibernate validator?

Comment: check what functionality has your version, maybe it´s true that the @annotation for validation does not work properly with your version

Comment: If you dont have any dependency limitation, I will try with this version and follow the documentation that I attach to check that works. In our case works like a charm

Comment: No. after applying your advise I don't see changes

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **`@Range`** annotation which is available in the `org.hibernate.validator.constraints` package.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Range.html

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Range;
...

@Entity
@Table(name = "terminal")
public class Terminal {
    @Column(name = "cost")
    @Range(min=100, message="Should be of min length 10.")
    private Long cost;
    // get and set
}
```

*I didn't compile this code. So they can be syntax errors.*

Comment: Unforunately, after your advise applying I don't see behaviour correction

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing JPA and Hibernate specific api. In your config file remove:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-persist">javax.validation.groups.Default</property>
<property name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-update">javax.validation.groups.Default</property>
```

and add

```
   <event type="pre-update">
     <listener class="org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener"/>
   </event>
   <event type="pre-insert">
     <listener class="org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener"/>
   </event>
```